# Are the objects in the following class immutable?

Tags: java, multithreading, class, immutability, mutable

```
public class Point {
       private double x;
       private double y;
       Point (double x, double y) 
       { this.x = x; this.y = y; }
       double getX() { return x; }
       double getY() { return y; }       }
```

Are the objects in the above class immutable? Explain.
I am getting confused because
There r no setters so nothing can modify the objects
BUT 
there is no final variable or final class which it should contain.

If the class gets extended, it could add extra fields that are not immutable, or the methods could be overridden to return a different value each time. Doesnt this make the class not immutable?

Comment: "Objects in", or "objects of"?

Comment: In some discussions, "immutable" means all of the fields are `final`, and a class like yours with fields that are not final, but which never are changed is called "effectively immutable".  There are some differences in how the constructor of the class synchronizes with methods called in other threads depending on whether the class is truly mmutable or only effectively immutable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If the class gets extended, ... the methods could be overridden to return a different value each time. Doesn't this make the class not immutable?

Your question is subtle.  If some `class MutPoint extends Point` and overrides the `getX()` and `getY()` methods to return non-constant values, that doesn't change the `Point` class itself.  Instances of `Point` sill will be effectively immutable, but a caller would be allowed to pass `MutPoint` objects to *your* methods that expect `Point` arguments.  What happens then?  Depends on how you write your code.  It *could* be that your code would behave badly if the caller gave you a Point-like object, and then subsequently changed its "value".

If your code that uses `Point` objects requires them to never change, then you might want to declare the whole class `final`

```
public final class Point { ... }
```

That way, your client will not be allowed to override the class, and will not be allowed to call your methods with anything other than an actual `Point` instance.

Comment: Though the fields of such class may not be altered, but since we have used "this.x" in the constructor, can it escape during construction?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are immutable. You can read about it here
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html

Comment: but isnt the use of "final" keyword necessary as docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/… mentions

Comment: It says "Not all classes documented as "immutable" follow these rules". It is also advised there to make your class final to prevent it from extension. In the end, I would say this class is immutable, but with comment that it could be done better :)

Comment: Though the fields of such class may not be altered, but since we have used "this.x" in the constructor, can it escape during construction thus making it mutable?

Comment: @raj247 There's no harm in using `this` in a constructor, but don't _pass_ `this` as an argument to any method belonging to another class or, to any instance method that could be overridden by a derived class.  Doing so would allow the other class/derived class to see `this` before the instance is fully initialized.  Don't do it even if it's the last statement in your constructor because the the foreign method could hand the `this` reference off to some other thread that would not be properly synchronized with the constructor call.

Comment: @jameslarge I think I am getting what you are saying but I cant see a clear picture. Can you please provide me with an example to make things more clear..? Thanks for the help..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because you can't accsess to the data member and you don't have method that change your data members

Comment: but isnt the use of "final" keyword necessary as http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/imstrat.html mentions.